# Opening problem of raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have a problem of opening of raspbian. I installed the raspbian and then after installing a dialogue box showed that installation is successful, after i press ok the monitor shows no signal and then i unplug and plug the rpi4 but after doing that it shows rainbow Screen and if i do nothing it shows no signal and if i press shift there is recovery and just installs it again. How to solve this?

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: @Hackerman, The below official Rpi 4 power requirements tutorial might help. For newbies, a cheap wall wart of 5V, 2A is usually more than enough (But of course rich guys go for "official" 3A or higher.).  And if risky you are using a cheap mobile phone charger, expect colourful rainbows first, to dizzy you, and yellow lighting bolts afterwards, to strike you! :)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-power

Comment: You have not indicated HOW you "installed the raspbian" or what version you are trying to install. If using an old version of NOOBS this is to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the Comments the rainbow screen **is unlikely to have anything to do with power supply** - it is indicative of missing/faulty boot files.

Again contrary to comments the Pi4 **does NOT REQUIRE** a 2A (or 3A - as recommended) power supply - it will boot and run on a good 1A supply, although a quality (official) supply is recommended.

See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558) which will help you diagnose your actual problem.

NOTE the rainbow screen is not a meaningful indicator on the Pi4.

You are recommended to download Raspbian and follow the installation guide.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Answer (score 0):

If it is stuck on rainbow pattern window then you are using a power source that can't supply minimum of 2A. Change your power supply and the problem will be solved. Use a power source of minimum 5V-2.5A .

Comment: please see this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55464

Comment: You should change your answer to 'stuck on the rainbow pattern' and a Pi4 requires 5.1V 3.0A. Lets see what the OP is using for power.

Comment: I think 5V-2.5A PSU minimum is a good advice. 3A minimum is over selling, especially to poor hobbyists like me.

Comment: For my fellow poor hobbyists, I always recommend them to read this official reference on Rpi power requirements (which more or less says 2A is more or less OK for poor guys.): https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-power.